# How to access file-name's ending (before the extension) in a loop

Tags: bash

I have a folder with file-names ending `.TIF`, and I did a for loop

```
for i in *.TIF
```

In the loop, I want to get two types of files ending for example (B4.TIF and B5.TIF.

I did it like this but, it doesn't get the last four letters of the file name, instead it adds them at the end.

```
do ...... ${i}_B4.TIF -B ${i}_B5.TIF
```

My desired results are to get those file names in order to do some calculations

these are the examples of the files in the folder

```
LC08_L1TP_195020_20170224_20170301_01_T1_B4.TIF  
LC08_L1TP_195020_20171107_20171121_01_T1_B4.TIF

LC08_L1TP_195020_20170224_20170301_01_T1_B5.TIF  
LC08_L1TP_195020_20171107_20171121_01_T1_B5.TIF
```

and this is the script I am using to do the calculations

```
for i in *.TIF   
do 
    gdal_calc.py -A ${i}_B4_SA.TIF -B ${i}_B5_SA.TIF --type=Float32
--outfile=~/Geodata/goteborg/croped/ndvi/${i}_NDVI.TIF --calc="(B-A)/(B+A)"

done
```

The final output will be subtracting the B4 and B5. so this `${i}_B4_SA.TIF -B ${i}_B5_SA.TIF` should get the two file names like this:

```
LC08_L1TP_195020_20170224_20170301_01_T1_B4.TIF - 
LC08_L1TP_195020_20170224_20170301_01_T1_B5.TIF
```

Comment: Please list an example input and output (just a few lines).

Comment: Why don't you loop over `./*B[45]_SA.TIF`?  Or do you need both files i the same iteration of the loop. Please explain more about what it is you're doing.

Comment: I need both files in the same iteration. see the example and the script in my last edit

Comment: I don't see an `_SA` in the examples, is this the problem.

Comment: Your example command takes two inputs and produces one output, but your list of example files doesn't have any "matches" between the `B4` and `B5` set.  Please indicate which pairs of input files you want to use together, and how you decide the output filename each time.

Comment: And show expected output.

Comment: I did provide now same files with different B4 and B5. I have copied different file names earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the files that constitute one half of the pairs, and for each such file, construct the filename of the corresponding pair and of the output file:

```
for b4_file in ./*_B4.TIF; do
    b5_file="${b4_file%_B4.TIF}_B5.TIF"
    ndvi_file="$HOME/Geodata/goteborg/croped/ndvi/${b4_file%_B4.TIF}_NDVI.TIF"

    if [ ! -f "$b5_file" ]; then
        printf 'Expected to find "%s" to go with "%s", but did not\n' "$b5_file" "$b4_file" >&2
        continue
    fi

    # do whatever it is you need to do with "$b4_file" and "$b5_file"

    gdal_calc.py -A "$b4_file" -B "$b5_file" --type=Float32 \
        --outfile="$ndvi_file --calc="(B-A)/(B+A)"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

First note there is no-such thing as a file extension on Unix. `.` is just another character. So here I search for some ½ of your files, strip the end of the name off, ready to put it back on (in two different ways).

This will sort of work, but may have some latent bugs.

```
for f in *_B5.TIF   
do 
    i="$(echo "$f" | sed -r -e 's/(.*)_B5.TIF/\1/')"
    … ${i}_B4_SA.TIF -B ${i}_B5_SA.TIF …
done
```

This should be more robust

```
find . -iname "*_B5.TIF" -print0 | sed -0r -e 's/(.*)_B5.TIF/\1/' | xargs -0 -i … {}_B4_SA.TIF -B {}_B5_SA.TIF …
```

Please test, as I have not (may be some small error). And there is no error checking. Your program must check for miss-matches.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Bash, you can use [Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to chop the ending and save the common part of the filename in a new variable:

```
for f in *_B4.TIF ; do
    i="${f%_B4.TIF}"
    gdal_calc.py -A "${i}_B4.TIF" -B "${i}_B5.TIF" --outfile=".../${i}_NDVI.TIF"
done
```